# How to count the numbers of letters for each column in a String [][]?

Tags: java

I want to count the number of letters in a `String [][]` by column , so far my code is this :

```
  for(int j = 0 ; j<matrix[0].length ;j++){
      for(int i  = 0 ; i< matrix.length ;i++ )
        if (Character.isLetter(matrix[j][i].charAt(j)))
        countChar++;
      }
      System.out.println(countChar + "letters");
      return countChar;
```

but the output of the program counts how many elements the string has 
for example if the String is :

```
String [][] C = {
  {"abc",    "abcd" ,        "abcd"},
  {"oroeo",  "kakakak" ,     "alsksjk"},
  {"abcdef", "asdasdasdasd", "asdasdasdasd"}, 
};
```

the result is 9 , but should be 14 (number of letters by column ) 
Any help is greatly apreciated thank you !

Comment: you're trying to count the number of characters in a column?

Comment: What do u mean by column, can you give an example, for some input what do you expect the output should be. you have given the example, but explain how should it count.

Comment: Sorry, but I think my answer below is much better than the one you currently accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a 2D matrix as an array of rows or an array of columns. I'm assuming you have defined it as an array of rows and now want to get the values in a certain column.

So your data looks like this:

```
abc             abcd             abcd
oroeo           kakakak          alsksjk
abcdef          asdasdasdasd     asdasdasdasd
```

three rows and three columns.

to get for example the values in the middle column (with index 1) you would need to get the array elements:

```
matrix[0][1]
matrix[1][1]
matrix[2][1]
```

I think you are trying to count the total of the lengths of all values in each column. That would go like this:

```
    // assume that the matrix has at least one row and thas the same number of columns in each row
    // take the number of columns in the first row for reference
    int numberOfColumns = matrix[0].length;
    for(int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; col++) {
        int count = 0;
        // iterate over all the rows
        for(String[] row : matrix) {
            // count the length of the element in position col of this row
            count += row[col].length();
        }
        System.out.printf("%s characters in column %s", count, col);
    }
```

Comment: You are right , I haven't seen your answer sorry about that ! and yes it is the better choice as it goes throw each column and counts the characters for each of them !

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = 0;
// iterate row by row
for (int i = 0; i < C.length; i++) {
    n += C[i][0].length();
    // get the string at index 0 (or 1 or 2.. whichever you want) of the array and append its length
    // if you expect the string to contain numbers, then
    // run a for-loop on the string and check if its a letter
}
System.out.println(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below the problem is with your for loop for which the no. of iterations are limited to the size of your matrix:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<C[0].length ;i++) {
                String matrixElement = C[i][0];
                System.out.println(matrixElement);
                for(int k =0 ;k < matrixElement.length();k++)
                if (Character.isLetter(matrixElement.charAt(k)))
                    countChar++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, format out your code and brush up the loop:

```
  private static int countByColumn(String[][] matrix, int column) {
    if (column < 0)
      return 0; // Or throw exception

    int countChar = 0;

    for (String[] line : matrix) {
      //DONE: jagged array: it may appear that the line is too short 
      if (line.length <= column) 
        continue;

      String item = line[column];

      for (int i = 0; i < item.length; ++i)
        if (Character.isLetter(item.charAt(i))) 
          countChar += 1;
    }  

    return countChar;
  }
```

Test:

```
  // 14
  int test = countByColumn(C, 0);
```